# Executar stored procedure no banco oracle em PHP

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, php-7, oracle11g

Tenho a `procedure` "**exemplo1**" a qual recebe 3 parâmetros de entrada e nenhum de saída, como faço para executar a mesma em `PHP`.

No caso seria assim.

```
EXEC "exemplo1"('para1','para1','para3');
```

Como fica o codigo em PHP testei assim e não deu certo

```
$sql = 'EXECUTE "PORTAL_importaXml"'. "(?,?,?)";
$stmt = Conecta::prepareOrc($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $p1);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $p2);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $p3);
return $stmt->execute();`
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Qual biblioteca de conexão você está usando? OCI8 ou PDO? Aparentemente é PDO.

Comment: Estou usando PDO, algum problema em relação ao uso dela? Se só funcionar na OCI8 tem algum exemplo para conexão.

Comment: O exemplo 5 é o que você precisa. Esta é a documentação oficial http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score -1):

Não precisa pôr aspas no nome da procedure:

```
$sql = 'EXECUTE PORTAL_importaXml (?,?,?)';
```

Comment: Desta maneira também não funcionou, utilizo para conectar o banco o PDO.